# How to add new parameters to solr query responses

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

I'm trying to run the below URL

`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=reqst00548008&fl=trendid,keywords,problem,general&sort=score+desc&debug=query&wt=json&indent=true&hl=true&hl.fl=keywords,problem,symptom,general&hl`

The response I get is as below

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"reqst00548008",
      "debug":"query",
      "hl":["true",
        ""],
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"trendid,keywords,problem,general",
      "sort":"score desc",
      "hl.fl":"keywords,problem,symptom,general",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "general":"NullPointerException seen in logs",
        "keywords":"NPE, NullPointerException",
        "trendid":"2064"}]
  },
  "highlighting":{
    "2064":{}},
  "debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"reqst00548008",
    "querystring":"reqst00548008",
    "parsedquery":"text:reqst00548008",
    "parsedquery_toString":"text:reqst00548008",
    "QParser":"LuceneQParser"}
}
```

I want to include problem also in response which I'm not able to do.

What I tried so far is to add that to the data-config.xml as below

```
<dataConfig> 
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
   driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
   url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=sustainingxxxx"
   user="max"
   password="xxxxxx"/>

    <document name="content">
        <entity name="id"
query="select id,createtime,lastmodified,modifiedby,title,keywords,general,symptom,diagnosis,resolution,problem FROM trends"
deltaImportQuery="select id,createtime,lastmodified,modifiedby,title,keywords,general,symptom,diagnosis,resolution,problem FROM trends WHERE id = ${dataimporter.delta.id}"
deltaQuery="select id FROM trends WHERE lastmodified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' or createtime > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">

            <field column="id" name="trendid" />
            <field column="lastmodified" name="lastmodified" />
            <field column="modifiedby" name="modifiedby" />
            <field column="title" name="title" />
            <field column="keywords" name="keywords" />
            <field column="general" name="general" />
            <field column="symptom" name="symptom" />
            <field column="diagnosis" name="diagnosis" />
            <field column="resolution" name="resolution" />
            <field column="problem" name="problem" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I added all the problem, but that didn't help. Do I need to mention that some where else? Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you post also the `schema.xml` of your index? This would help

Comment: I have attached the same @ https://pastebin.com/raw/7AM129Fz

please let me know if you have any difficulty in downloading the same

Comment: I have just written my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `problem` does not exist in your `schema.xml` file that's why you cannot see it in your query results.

```
<field name="trendid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="lastmodified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="modifiedby" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="title" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="keywords" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="general" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="symptom" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="diagnosis" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="resolution" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

You have to add the field in your schema, if you do not have particular text analysis needs just add:

```
<field name="problem" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

So you can reload the core configuration or restart your Solr instance.

Then you have reload the data into your index.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.. One more query I have is, I want to sort the results based on lastmodified time. I assume I should be changing something in the url to make it happen?

Comment: Yep, instead of use `&sort=score+desc` try with `&sort=lastmodified+desc`. Then you can refine your sort choosing between `asc` or `desc`.